# Meaning of dot in lm(y~.) in R

Tags: r

I am trying to understand the meaning of this statement in R in a code written by somebody else.

```
mymodel = lm(gene ~ ., data = mydata)
```

`mydata` is as follows:

```
> mydata
                 gene    cna rs11433683      PC1    PC2
TCGA.BH.A0C0 270.7446 0.1291          0 270.7446 0.1291
TCGA.A2.A3XY  87.9092 0.0128          1  87.9092 0.0128
TCGA.XX.A89A 255.1346 0.1530          1 255.1346 0.1530
```

I have gone through the R help section to find how `.` is interpreted. I understand that `.` is typically not used, but this is what I found

```
help(formula)
```

> There are two special interpretations of `.` in a formula. The usual
>   one is in the context of a `data` argument of model fitting functions
>   and means ‘all columns not otherwise in the formula’: see
>   `terms.formula`.  In the context of `update.formula`, *only*, it means
>   ‘what was previously in this part of the formula’

```
help(terms.formula)
```

> AllowDotAsName: normally `.` in a formula refers to the remaining
>   variables contained in `data`. Exceptionally, `.` can be treated as a
>   name for non-standard uses of formulae.
>
> `data`: a data frame from which the meaning of the special symbol `.` can be inferred.  It is unused if there is no `.` in the formula.

However, I am not really sure what the statements mean. Can somebody give me a simple example of what it means in the context of statement and data I mentioned above?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10712/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dot-in-r

Comment: It means use all other variables (cna, rs..., pc1 and pc2) as independent variables in the model.

Comment: It's exactly what it says it is: `all the columns` (from the data supplied to the `data` parameter) `not otherwise in the formula`. In this case, since `gene` is supplied, the rest are taken as explanatory variables, so `gene ~ .` is equivalent to `gene ~ cna + rs11433683 + PC1 + PC2`. Explanations will only go so far, though; try it out and look at the difference in the resulting model.

Comment: \*To be clear, that's what `.` means _in a formula_. Some packages use it to mean other things, particularly when piping or as a function.

Comment: Thanks guys.. that makes a lot of sense now.. I wish an example like what you just mentioned was included in the help() section. I wouldnt have spent so many hours banging my head and searching in the helpfiles.. Is there a way to suggest this change in R documentation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> in the context of a data argument of model fitting functions and means ‘all columns not otherwise in the formula’

Exactly what it says there on the box!

So with

```
 mymodel = lm(gene ~ ., data = mydata)
```

you get every variable *other than* `gene` that's in `mydata` on the RHS of the formula:

```
   cna + rs11433683 + PC1 + PC2
```

As far as I can see, the quoted phrase is clear and unambiguous (... but you could also see it just from trying a few small examples)

The only thing that might not be obvious is what it does if you didn't supply a `data` argument (but that's answered in the help of `terms.formula` that is referred to in your quote).

Comment: I agree that in hindsight, the quoted text seems clear, as soon as I saw the example. However, "The usual one is in the context of a data argument of model fitting functions and means ‘all columns not otherwise in the formula’: see  terms.formula" doesnt necessarily lead the reader to understand that y~. is equivalent to y~a+b+c... where a,b,c are the other columns of data, especially if they are new to the field. The help section is written in dense text, and assumes a high degree of familiarity with R already..

Answer (score 0):

Means you are comparing gene to all the variables