# Difference between . and 1 in glm

Tags: regression, glm

I want to perform a regression and first of all I want to test if my nullmodel is significant. 
So if not, I wont be able to perform the stepwise introduction according to AIC.

So I did the following:

```
m0 <- glm(Y~ 1, data = Data, family = binomial)
summary(m0)
```

So I have seen on the internet that some people use this code:

```
model <- glm(Y ~ .,data = Data, family=binomial) 
summary(model)
```

What I want to know is whats the difference between the dot (.) and the 1.

Thank you :)

Comment: "*If not, I wont be able to perform the stepwise introduction according to AIC*". That sounds suspicious. I mean, stepwise regresssion is widely discouraged and recognized as dubious, but I've never heard any conditions on the null model for it to "work". As for how to proceed, I would recommend a regularized regression such as the Lasso or a Bayesian model.

Comment: Yes, I think testing if the null model is significant is pointless - basically it's just asking if your data is centered or not. And I also think very poorly of stepwise regression in general. As I said in my first comment, I would recommend a regularized regression such as the Lasso or a Bayesian model. stats.stackexchange [has a nice Q/A about automatic model selection here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20836/7515).

Comment: I don't understand your new question. The question you posted was about how to do feature selection, and I gave you my recommendation. Now it seems like you are asking *"How about I don't do feature selection, I just use all my variables. Will that work?"* No one can answer that without knowing your data and your goal in the analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Y is the dependent variable the right is the independent variable, the . is short hand for all the other variables

Y ~ val  means model Y with val
Y ~ . means the model against all the other variables

[Meaning of dot in lm(y~.) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655679/meaning-of-dot-in-lmy-in-r)