# What do the dot (".") and the tilde ("~") represent in R?

Tags: r

I've been running regressions for some months now and just realized I've been writing things without truly understanding the code.

For example, I am now running:

```
logit <- glm(loan_result ~ . -annual_income, data = train_set, family = "binomial")
```

I realize the command means: "*use all the variables in `train_set` except for `anual income` to model loan_result using a logit model."*

I have no idea what the dot and the tilde mean separately or how to use them individually in any other function. Could someone explain the meaning of these two characters please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655679/meaning-of-dot-in-lmy-in-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the "Formula" syntax
`~` is read as "in function of"
and `.` means all other variables
in this case you have
`load_result` in function of every other variable except `annual_income`