# R combinations with dot ("."), "~", and pipe (%>%) operator

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, magrittr

I have been looking to a lot of answers and still I can't completely understand them. For example, the clearest one ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560450/what-do-dot-and-percentage-mean-in-r)), among others ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562671/what-do-the-dot-and-the-tilde-represent-in-r),[2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10712/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dot-in-r),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655679/meaning-of-dot-in-lmy-in-r)) gives specific examples about the various uses of the dot but I cannot understand, for example, its application here:

```
car_data <- 
  mtcars %>%
  subset(hp > 100) %>%
  aggregate(. ~ cyl, data = ., FUN = . %>% mean %>% round(2)) %>%
  transform(kpl = mpg %>% multiply_by(0.4251)) %>%
  print

#result:
  cyl   mpg  disp    hp drat   wt  qsec   vs   am gear carb    kpl
1   4 25.90 108.0 111.0 3.94 2.15 17.75 1.00 1.00 4.50 2.00 11.010
2   6 19.74 183.3 122.3 3.59 3.12 17.98 0.57 0.43 3.86 3.43  8.391
3   8 15.10 353.1 209.2 3.23 4.00 16.77 0.00 0.14 3.29 3.50  6.419
```

The code above is from an [explanation for %>% in magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html), where I'm trying to understand the pipe operator also (I know that it gives you the result of the previous computation, but I get lost in the `aggregate` code line when it mixes `.`, and `%>%` inside the same function.

So, I can't understand what does the code above. I have the result (I put it above). But I don't get how it reach that result, specially the `aggregate` code line, where it uses the dot and the `~` sign. I know that `~` means "all other variables", but what it means with the dot? It has another meaning or application? And what does the pipe operator inside a specific function?

Comment: I think what's confusing here is the different use of `.` in the formula in the `aggregate` call and in terms of its use in the `magrittr` package. Per `?formula`: "There are two special interpretations of . in a formula. The usual one is in the context of a data argument of model fitting functions and means ‘all columns not otherwise in the formula’: see terms.formula. In the context of update.formula, only, it means ‘what was previously in this part of the formula’."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That line uses the `.` in three different ways.

```
         [1]             [2]      [3]
aggregate(. ~ cyl, data = ., FUN = . %>% mean %>% round(2))
```

Generally speaking you pass in the value from the pipe into your function at a specific location with `.` but there are some exceptions. One exception is when the `.` is in a formula. The `~` is used to create formulas in R. The pipe wont change the meaning of the formula, so it behaves like it would without any escaping. For example

```
aggregate(. ~ cyl, data=mydata)
```

And that's just because `aggregate` requires a formula with both a left and right hand side. So the `.` at `[1]` just means "all the other columns in the dataset." This use is not at all related to magrittr.

The `.` at `[2]` is the value that's being passed in as the pipe. If you have a plain `.` as a parameter to the function, that's there the value will be placed. So the result of the `subset()` will go to the `data=` parameter.

The `magrittr` library also allows you to define anonymous functions with the `.` variable. If you have a chain that starts with a `.`, it's treated like a function. so

```
. %>% mean %>% round(2)
```

is the same as

```
function(x) round(mean(x), 2)
```

so you're just creating a custom function with the `.` at `[3]`

Answer (score 4):

Dot is used in three ways in the aggregate statement:

- **aggregate.formula** the `formula` method of `aggregate` specifies a formula in which the left hand side (LHS) of the ~ defines the variables to apply the function to and the right hand side of the ~ defines the variables to group by.  It uses dot in the formula to mean all other variables not already mentioned in the formula. For example, using the builtin `ToothGrowth` data frame having columns `len`, `supp` and `dose` these are the same.  We group by `supp` whereas `mean` acts on each of `len` and `dose`.

  ```
  aggregate(. ~ supp, ToothGrowth, mean)
  aggregate(cbind(len, dose) ~ supp, ToothGrowth, mean)
  ```
- **RHS of pipe** when used on the right hand side (RHS) of a pipe magrittr uses dot to represent the input, i.e. whatever is on the left hand side of the pipe.  Thus, these are the same:

  ```
  4 %>% sqrt(.) # use of dot on RHS
  sqrt(4)
  ```
- **LHS of pipe** when used on the left hand side of a pipe magrittr uses dot to represent a function definition.  For example, these two function defintions both define a function that squares its argument:

  ```
  square1 <- . %>% .^2 # use of dot on LHS
  square2 <- function(x) x^2
  ```

Perhaps it is easiest to see if we write the example in the question without dot:

```
mtcars0 <-  mtcars %>%
  subset(hp > 100)

aggregate(
  cbind(mpg,disp,hp,drat,wt,qsec,vs,am,gear,carb) ~ cyl,  # cbind(...) in place of .
  data = mtcars0, # mtcars0 in place of .
  FUN = function(x) round(mean(x), 2)) # instead of . %>% etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

As there are multiple functions acting in a sequential manner, an option would be to use `compose`

```
library(tidyverse)
f1 <- list(mean,  partial(round, digits = 2))
mtcars %>% 
    filter(hp > 100) %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    summarise_all(list(~lift(compose)(f1)(.))) %>% 
    mutate(kpl = mpg * 0.4251) #multiply_by is a bit verbose
```