# When doing a t-test with t.test() while piping, what does the period do in "data=."?

Tags: r, magrittr, hypothesis-test

I have a data frame with 2 columns being age and sex. I'm doing statistical analysis to determine if there's a difference in the age distribution in the two groups of sex. I know that if I don't call **data=** it will give an error (I believe it's something w/ the dplyr library). I was wondering what the single **.** in the **data** parameter does. Does it direct it to the data frame we used before the %>% ?

```
age_sex.htest <- d %>%
   t.test(formula=age~sex, data=.)
```

Comment: The `lhs` is passed to `data` argument of `t.test`. You can read about the pipe operator here: https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html#arguments

Comment: Relevant: [R combinations with dot ("."), "~", and pipe (%>%) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54815607/r-combinations-with-dot-and-pipe-operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @markus has pointed out, `d` is passed to the `data` argument in `t.test`. Here is the output from `data(sleep)` using the `.`.

```
library(dplyr)
data(sleep)

sleep %>% t.test(formula=extra ~ group, data = .)

# Output
    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  extra by group
t = -1.8608, df = 17.776, p-value = 0.07939
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means between group 1 and group 2 is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -3.3654832  0.2054832
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
           0.75            2.33
```

If you put `sleep` directly into `data` of `t.test`, then you will get the same result, as `t.test` is running the exact same data.

```
t.test(formula=extra ~ group, data = sleep)

# Output

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  extra by group
t = -1.8608, df = 17.776, p-value = 0.07939
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means between group 1 and group 2 is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -3.3654832  0.2054832
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
           0.75            2.33
```

In this case, the `.` is not that beneficial, though some people prefer this stylistically (I generally do).

However, it is extremely useful when you want to run the analysis on a slight alteration of the dataframe. So, with the sleep dataset, for example, if you wanted to remove `ID == 10` from both groups, then you could remove those with `filter`, and then run the `t.test`.

```
sleep %>%
  filter(ID != 10) %>%
  t.test(formula = extra ~ group, data = .)
```

So, we pass an altered version of the `sleep` dataset without the rows where ID is 10. So now, we will see a change in the output:

```
    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  extra by group
t = -1.7259, df = 15.754, p-value = 0.1039
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means between group 1 and group 2 is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -3.5677509  0.3677509
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
      0.6111111       2.2111111
```